# Refresh div after POST

Tags: php, jquery, refresh

I'd like to refresh the div when a message is deleted from my cat How to make it work?
 
I've put a piece of code. 
Thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function deleteBox(id){
                              if (confirm("Confirnez-vous la suppression du message?"))
                              {
                                var dataString = 'id='+ id;
                                       $.ajax({
                                       type: "POST",
                                       url: "del.php",
                                       data: dataString,
                                       cache: false,
                                       success: function(result){
                                       if(result){

                                    // if data delete successfully
                                    if(result=='success'){  
                                    //Check random no, for animated type of effect
                                    var randNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
                                    if(randNum % 2==0){
                                    // Delete with slide up effect
                                    $("#chat-item_"+id).slideUp(1000);

                                    // HERE

                                    }else{
                                    // Just hide data
                                    $("#chat-item_"+id).hide(500);

                                    }
                                    }else{
                                    var errorMessage=result.substring(position+2);
                                    alert(errorMessage);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                   });
                                }
                            }
    </script>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: your cat is sending messages! cleaver cat!

Comment: It's a example, you have an idea ?

Comment: Clever*, clever @Dagon. Refresh the div? Isn't this the whole point of using DOM manipulation, so you don't have to 'refresh' anything?

Answer (score 0):

In  your del.php file you can run a query that gets all messages after you have deleted the one you want. Then echo the html to fill the div.

Then on your Javascript side you can have it set the div's html to the data that is echoed back('results' variable).

Comment: Up please. help me :(